# I want to change the mouse pointer from text to pointer when particular values in a dropdown are selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can I change the pointer on  element only when saab or audi is selected. I cannot  use href attribute.

```js
<script>
$(document).on('change','#dropdown',function(){
    if($("#dropdown").find("option:selected").val()=="saab"){
 $('#link').css('cursor:pointer');
    }
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<a id="link">link text</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: `dropdown` is class not an id so you need to use `.dropdown` not `#dropdown` or change `class="dropdown"` with `id="dropdown"`

2nd: with select enough to use `$('select').val()` instead of using the `.find("option:selected")`

3rd: with `.css()` function you can use `.css('cursor' ,'pointer')` or `.css({'cursor' :'pointer'})`

So you can use the next code

```js
$(document).on('change','.dropdown',function(){
    $('#link').css('cursor' , $(this).val() =="saab" ? 'pointer' : 'text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<a id="link">link text</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and help Mohamed

Comment: Your totally Welcome @ritesh .. Have a great day :-)